# router not getting address from DHCP

Tags: router, ip, wireless-router, ethernet, dhcp

In an office building, I plug a computer into a network drop in one of the offices. I get an IP address and access to the Internet. I needed to setup a private network for file sharing. So I set up an old Linksys router, reset it and updated the firmware. When I plug in the cable to the network drop and login to the router, it does not get an IP address. 0.0.0.0.

So I went out and bought a new, cheap, router. When I plug into that the light doesn't even light up on the router. It's as if nothing is plugged in. I used the same cable that worked on the PC. I logged into the router and verified there is no IP. This router even goes so far as to say nothing is plugged in. However, if I plug the computer directly into the WAN port, it lights up. So it's not new router that is bad.

Is there something that could be configured on the WAN side of this local router, in the office building, that is stopping me from getting an IP on a router? I am sure I am plugged into the WAN/Internet port. I have set 100's of these up and never seen such an issue. I know there is a Sonicwall device on the larger network, but am not privy to much else.

I also changed the IP range for the DHCP on the router thinking that maybe I was having a conflict. That didn't work. And then later I found that these devices don't even see the cable as plugged in, neither the Linksys nor the new router. I also tried a brand new cable to the device and that did not make a difference.

What am I missing? What else should I try? Thanks!!!

Comment: Ask the people who set up the network drop. Normally you can set up a vanilla router for WAN DHCP and it will get an address. So the network setup may be preventing this. That puts the router on a different subnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being bad cabling. Just wanted to close this out. Thanks to everyone who contributed!

Answer (score 2):

The WAN port of a router is the port that provide it access to the internet. The LAN ports are what provide its network to the clients.

So the WAN port goes into the wall outlet, and your pc goes into the LAN port.

Then refer to the manual on how to access and configure the DHCP of that router if it isn't enabled already by default.

Once you got it setup such that you can use the router, set its internet access to DHCP, which on most routers is the default.

If you plugin the network cable that provides internet into one of the LAN ports of the router, then indeed, it won't have internet access because internet is only accessible through its WAN port. That's basically what a router does. Shield all LAN ports from internet and uses the router capabilities through NAT translation to open ports between the WAN port and the individual LAN ports.

If that still doesn't work, then the sonicwall is detecting that the client is a router and there is a policy active preventing any router from gaining access. In that case, you need to contact your network-/system administrators.

Comment: I understand the proper setup, and appreciate your detailed response. I do believe it must be that something in the Sonicwall device is detecting it as a router. I was not sure this was possible but suspected something was happening that distinguished the two. What sort of policy should I be looking for? The building IT staff were less than helpful and blamed it immediately on the routers. If I could take some sort of information to them to troubleshoot this they will likely take me more seriously. Thanks!!!

Comment: Can't help you with that, I'm afraid. I just know that sonic walls can be configured to not allow a router inside its network. It sounds like your IT staff is fully aware of this and just wants to get rid of you quickly without explaining why the company has a policy against using routers.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a third party and the IT staff says that the network is "fully open". I suspect they are unaware of the policies on the device. I appreciate the reply!!